# why do i keep getting vector cannot name type error in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I keep getting the error "vector does not name type" from one of my classes each time I try to compile my code.

```
 #ifndef DISK
#define DISK
#include "PageTableEntry.h"
#include <vector>
class disk{
  private:
    Vector <PageTableEntry*> frames;
  public:
        void addFrame(int Location, PageTableEntry* pte);
    void removeFrame(int pteLocation);
    Disk();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Oops: `Vector` should be `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You should quote errors verbatim. I assume the error is actually more along the lines of `Vector does not name type`.

You have either not included the declaration for `Vector` in your code, doing so would provide the compiler with a [type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type), or you have (more likely) mistakenly written `Vector` when it should be `std::vector`. Letter case and namespaces matter in C++.

Try:

```
std::vector<PageTableEntry*> frames;
```